# I cant get the ID from the url using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to develop a blog site. Here is my problem: I can't get the id from the url.

Using my htaccess (I removed index.php), this is now my current link: http://localhost/blogcodeigniter/posts/test_title_id_1

Here is my function from the controller:

```
public function post_look_up() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    echo $id;
}
```

Here is my routes:

```
$route['posts/(:any)']='blog/post_look_up';
```

Comment: What is actually going wrong? Maybe you could elaborate a little more on what the specific problem at hand is, and how you tried to solve it so far.

Comment: The id should be stored in $id from the url, but it doesn't, therefore when I echo $id, I don't see any echo. I know for a fact that the function post_look_up() works because when I include $this->load->view('header_view'); to the function, I see my header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take this convention, you have to identify last number in a string.

```
$segment = $this->uri->segment(2); //or  3
$post_id = preg_replace('(\d+)$', '', $segment);
```

But I wouldnt go this way. I would load the post based on slug only, use only $this->uri->segment(2) to get post from db.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've rewriten your `controller/method` you would like to use URI class' `rsegment()` method

```
$id = $this->uri->rsegment(3);
```

or

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

You can see your newly set route would have 2 segments only.
[Reference](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::rsegment).